# how to get location (#-th line) of EObject in original document?

Tags: validation, xtext

The followings are my grammar rules:

```
Stmts: (stmts += Stmt ';')* ;
Stmt: Stmt1 | Stmt2 | Stmt3 ... ;
```

I want to know each Stmt# is #-th stmt in stmts and their exactly location (#-th line in original document). Such that I could point out the location when user make mistakes.

I override the validator constructor and store an `HashMap <Stmt, Integer>` to get each Stmt# is the #-th Stmt in stmts(Not sure if this is the correct way to do though...). However I have no idea how to get their line number.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given an EObject you can easily get the position in the source file using `org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.util.NodeModelUtils.getNode(EObject)`.

For example:

```
    INode node = NodeModelUtils.getNode(o);
    System.out.println(String.format("Node goes from line %s to line %s",node.getStartLine(), node.getEndLine()));
```

Comment: If I put the first line in any @Check annotated method I'll get `- This expression is not allowed in this context, since it doesn't
   cause any side effects.`, where did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't know which @Check annotation you put in here, but I think I can explain the error message. If you only put the first line in, you are only reading a value, but not changing anything. So the reading is pointless, if you don't do anything with the value you read. Put in both lines and the error should go away.

Comment: I know what happened...I'm using xtext 2.4 and default language of xtext validator is xtend not java. First line in xtend should be `val INode node = NodeModelUtils.getNode(o);` Thank you Stefan, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

For pointing out mistakes simply writing a declarative validator is better suited - in that case, you simply give Xtext problematic EObject, and it manages to trace it back to the source. Furthermore, a validator stub is generated in your language project.

However, if you need to manually trace back the nodes, there is the Injectable ILocationInFileProvider that can help you.